# How to retrieve Image preview from Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve only a preview of an image without for instance downloading the entire image of 4MB. (I use Glide). The purpose would be to download multiple (smaller) images quickly compared to 100MB of images.

Comment: maybe you need this https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/generate-thumbnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Glide library for Android](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) automatically caches the images on your local device. So if the size of an image is 4MB, then the image on your local storage will be 4MB too. It's true that you can create a preview of an image by resizing it as needed in code, but the amount of data that is downloaded and the size of the image on the disk will remain the same.

So if you only need a small preview of a 4MB image, then you should also add the preview of that image to the Firebase Storage too. This kind of image is called the thumbnail of the image. You can create the thumbnail yourself in code, or you can use:

- [Resize Images Extension from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images)

> Use this extension to create resized versions of an image uploaded to a Cloud Storage bucket.

So using this Extension, the hard work is done for you behind the scenes. So you'll be able to get only the thumbnail that will have the size of only a few KB. However, if you need the entire 4MB image, then you can access it on demand.

Comment: I Have not come around to implementing your solution but thanks very much for the idea. I will be uploading thumbnails with the original and then just downloading the thumbnails.